# VSCodeで折りたたみが勝手に開いてしまう

Tags: python, python3, vscode

VSCodeの最新版にpythonの最新版を入れてコードを書いています
一連のコードを,クラス名や関数名レベルで折りたたんで,必要な部分のみ展開して編集しているのですが
編集中の一時的なインデント崩れなどをきっかけに,そこから下の全折りたたみが勝手に開いてしまいます

vscodeの機能かpylanceのせいか分からないのですが,どうにかして開かないようにできないでしょうか
なお構文,型チェックは今まで通り行ってほしいです

(というかほぼデフォルト設定でvscodeなど使ってるので仕様の動作のような気もするのですが
コレみなさんどうされてるのでしょうか. あまり畳んでないのか,即畳み直しですか? )

[image: よい]

[image: よくない]

Comment: > `VSCodeの最新版にpythonの最新版を` とありますが、具体的なバージョンが記載されていないと状況の再現が難しそうです。また、他のプラグインは一切インストールしていないのでしょうか？

Comment: 現状1.67.2/3.10.2venvですが,実は結構前から我慢しているので､別に最新版でなくとも再現します. 再現が難しそうですとのことですが,そちらの環境ではこうならないのですか ?

Comment: > `現状1.67.2/3.10.2venv` `1.67.2` はVSCodeのバージョンですが、 `3.10.2venv` はPythonの仮想環境のバージョンのようです。 > `そちらの環境ではこうならないのですか ?` はい、なりません。

Comment: あなたの使っているVSCodeの設定や、使用しているプラグインとそのバージョンを詳細に記載することで、お困りの内容を再現して解決方法を回答できる方が現れるかもしれませんが、現状では再現も不可能でしたので、回答を期待できなさそうです。また、今後別の方がこの質問にたどり着いたとき、バージョンが異なるのが原因で参考にならない場合もあります。そのため、お使いの環境情報を詳細に記載することをおすすめします。 こちらもご参考ください： [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方 - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: vscodeやpythonを何度かインストール･アンインストール/アップデートしつつ使ってきたのですが毎回同じようになるのでそういう仕様なのかと思っていました.が,ならないということはおま環のようですね. ちょっと完全アンインストールからやり直してみます

Comment: 結局すべて初期化してvscodeを入れ直し,日本語化とpylanceとpython拡張機能だけ入った初期状態にしましたが再発しますね. 逆にならない方のバージョンやOS,設定類をお聞きしたい. pylance無効化しているとかでしょうか?

Comment: Pythonの「一時的なインデント崩れなど」で開く について, 今ひとつ, どういった操作か不明です。
こちらでは(必要なら事前に複数行選択しておいて) TAB / Shift-TAB 利用してインデントしてるけど, それでどうやってインデント崩れ起こすのか。それとも SPC連打なのか。

Comment: VS Codeの `.md`の折り畳みはよく使うけど Python折り畳みはほとんど使ってないですが,
`.md` に関して 1.66 or 1.67辺りでアクティビティバー？の「ソース管理」が砂時計後に折りたたみ解除されることが度々発生してます (editor.foldingMaximumRegions辺りかと思うが放置中)。それに近い話なら「少し前から変」と言えなくもないですが